# Spring boot 2 Undertow, not work set UndertowOptions.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL

Tags: spring-boot

Springboot 2.0

When navigating through type references: localhost:9093/?foo=bar|bar

> Return error: Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal
>   character in query

I'm adding an extra option:

```
@Component
public class MyWebServerCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<UndertowServletWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
    public void customize(UndertowServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addBuilderCustomizers(builder-> builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL, Boolean.TRUE));
    }        
}
```

Does not work, the exception is still.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
@Configuration
public class HttpConfig {
    @Bean
    public UndertowServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory(ApplicationProperties properties) {
        UndertowServletWebServerFactory factory = new UndertowServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addBuilderCustomizers((UndertowBuilderCustomizer) builder ->
            builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL, Boolean.TRUE));
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Request you to explain your logic and coding part by writing and highlighting valuable points.

Comment: This is also a solution for embedded Spring Boot undertow. It helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the parameters

```
myUrl = "localhost:9093/?" + URLEncoder.encode("foo=bar|bar", "UTF-8");
```

please refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_urlencode.asp) for url encoding. Say suppose if you want to send bar|bar. You can send as bar%7Cbar.

Here `%7C` is PIPE Character.

Comment: I need to process just such requests: foo = bar|bar

Comment: just try my solution.